# GeForce 8400 GS fan stops turning on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, fan

A user sent back their graphics card to me because he said that his screen kept blacking out.  When I first turned the computer back on I noticed that the fan wasn't spinning very fast on the video card.  Initially I thought this was maybe the issue, but, upon inspection of booting the machine up further, I noticed that the fan on the card began to spin as normal.  However, as the machine sat in my office for a bit longer and I did other things, I noticed the fan stopped completely; and that after giving it a spin with my finger it began to turn again at the normal rate.  The fan did not stop again.  It must be some sort of a fluke you would think if there was a mechanical problem with the fan it would stop moving immediately.  Are these cards known for having bad fans?  Is the driver causing the fan to turn on and off depending on the temperature of the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may have been a fluke - you should definitely return the part for a replacement.

As the 8400 GS is a current generation model, NVIDIA should still have this covered by warranty.

As far as I am aware - the driver never stops the fan completely - only slows it down.  As someone who has used exclusively nvidia card for years now in a clear case, I've never noticed my card fan stopped.  I've also just attempted turning off both my screens, leaving my pc alone for 5 mins (curiosity from your question) and the fan never stopped.

I've had a quick google and there aren't any noteworthy reports of fans stopping other than the odd complaint about dud cards - none of which related directly to this card.